# Colour lines by mean of value pairs in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When mapping colour to lines in ggplot2, e.g.:

```
x = data.frame(x = 1:6, y = c(0,0,10,10,0,0))
ggplot(x, aes(x, y, col=y)) + geom_line(size=5)
```

[image]

.. the lines colours are mapped to the first data point of each line segment.  Is there any easy way to get ggplot to calculate the mean value of both points instead (ie. so the sloping lines are both scaled to the colour for 5)?

Comment: What about calculating average values between two points and use that column to assign colors?

Comment: Sure, but that gets tricky when subsetting for multiple lines, and depending on your data structure. Guess I'm being lazy, but I'm just wonder if there's a ggplot solution..

Comment: With the given data, the two answers are doing the job, I think. `temp <- mutate(x, foo = (lead(y, default = 0) + y) / 2); ggplot(temp, aes(x = x, y = y, col = foo)) + geom_line(size=5)` would do the same job. If you have more complicated situation, I think it is worth adding more description in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar idea as @Richard, but use the `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
x = data.frame(x = 1:6, y = c(0,0,10,10,0,0))
ggplot(x, aes(x, y, col=rollmean(y, 2, fill = 0))) + geom_line(size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Easier to wrap into ggplot so I think this is the answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
x = data.frame(x = 1:6, y = c(0,0,10,10,0,0))
x$c <- rowMeans(cbind(x$y, c(x$y[-1], NA)))
ggplot(x, aes(x, y, col=c)) + geom_line(size=5)
```

Comment: Elegant way to calculate mid-values